# How to fine-tune iscsi-multipath queueing timeout?

Tags: centos, centos6, iscsi, multipath

I'm tuning the configuration for a multipath iscsi on a Centos 6 server.
At the moment I'm using the following parameters for path retry:

```
...
polling_interval 1
no_path_retry 12
...
```

That means, 'if a path fails, keep the I/O requests in queue for 12 seconds, then set them as failed'.

I'm thinking about increase the timeout to 60 seconds (`no_path_retry 60`) but I'm worried about the impact on my system.

I know the I/O wait (and thus the load) will rise a lot, and I consider it unavoidable under this circumstance, but is it going to eat up all my RAM? Will the system eventually crash?

Consider the average I/O through this multipath is about 30MB/s.

Answer (score 1):

`no_path_retry` is not a timeout in seconds, but is the number of retries until the failure is reported to the upper block device (e.g. file system). It accepts `queue` as value, which means that retry indefinitely and never report the error. This will freeze any I/O. If you care about data, and you do not mind if your application is frozen when all paths are unavailable, then use `queue`. If you do not care about data and you want your application to receive a file system error, then use an integer value. If you do not know what to do, use `queue`.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/dm_multipath/config_file_multipath

> **no_path_retry**
>   A numeric value for this attribute specifies the
>   number of times the system should attempt to use a failed path before
>   disabling queuing. A value of fail indicates immediate failure,
>   without queuing. A value of `queue` indicates that queuing should not
>   stop until the path is fixed.